# The `type` is not updating when creating or updating index

Tags: json, elasticsearch, post, kibana

I'm new to Kibana and Elasticsearch. I have task to migrate data from our production site to staging. Currently, I have given a simple code on creating index.
I have successfully created index, but upon comparing to production site, the `type` declared as `date` became `text` on my new site. We have noticed that all types are converting to `text` and not sure is because we are using new version of kibana.

Here in production site...

```
"authorizationDate": {
   "type": "date",
   "ignore_malformed": true,
   "format": "yyyy/MM/dd||yyyy-MM-dd"
},
```

This is how I implemented on staging site...

```
POST /orders/_doc/1 
{
  "order": {
    "properties": {
      "authorization": {
        "authorizationDate": {
          "type": "date",
          "ignore_malformed": true,
          "format": "yyyy/MM/dd||yyyy-MM-dd"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Upon checking...

```
GET orders?pretty
```

Output in orders mapping...

```
"mappings" : {
  "properties" : {
    "order" : {
      "properties" : {
        "properties" : {
          "properties" : {
            "authorization" : {
              "properties" : {
                "authorizationDate" : {
                  "properties" : {
                    "format" : {
                      "type" : "text",
                      "fields" : {
                        "keyword" : {
                          "type" : "keyword",
                          "ignore_above" : 256
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "ignore_malformed" : {
                      "type" : "boolean"
                    },
                    "type" : {
                      "type" : "text",
                      "fields" : {
                        "keyword" : {
                          "type" : "keyword",
                          "ignore_above" : 256
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
```

The `type` became text instead of date, and the date format is not recorded.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POST /orders/_doc/1 -- This will create a new index named orders with a default inferred mapping.
When you are running above it is treating "order", "properties", "ignore_malformed" as fields not part of mapping. hence you can see multiple nested properties in output mapping below.

```
"properties" : {
        "properties" : {
          "properties" : {
```

To create a new mapping first you should run

```
PUT orders       ---> create a new index named orders
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "authorization": {
        "type": "object",   --->should be object/nested was not present in your quest
        "properties": {
          "authorizationDate": {
            "type": "date",
            "ignore_malformed": true,
            "format": "yyyy/MM/dd||yyyy-MM-dd"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then adding a new doc using

```
POST /orders/_doc/1
{
  "authorization":{
    "authorizationDate":"2019-01-01"
  }
}
```

will give below data

```
 [
      {
        "_index" : "orders12",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "authorization" : {
            "authorizationDate" : "2019-01-01"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

Link for (Mapping)[https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html]

Comment: Thank you for very clear explanation. I understood now.